# Loop buffered video after getting error in videoView android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I want to repeat buffered video after getting error in the `VideoView`

I have play my video with the following code:

```
  public void playVideo() {


        if (!isAdded()) {
            return;
        }

        try {

            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_20mb.mp4");
            videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(
                    getActivity()));
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApplicationClass.gLogger.out("Error Happened in initializing ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);

            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {

                //playVideo again;
                if (i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED || i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO || i == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

every thing is ok, but when I lost my connection my video not looping.

on Error listener called with `MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO`. I want to loop my buffered video.

what I have tried in onError listener?

call `playVideo()` method again.

use `mediaPlayer.seekTo()` and `mediaPlayer.start()`.

use `videoView.seekTo()`.

I search a lot in SO and see many links but not worked for me.

as we can't get buffer data from VideoView, I can't save buffer data to a file and read from that.

thanks in advance

**// UPDATE**

seek not working in videoView because as in source of VideoView mentioned, when we call seek method following method called:

```
private boolean isInPlaybackState() {
        return (mMediaPlayer != null &&
                mCurrentState != STATE_ERROR &&
                mCurrentState != STATE_IDLE &&
                mCurrentState != STATE_PREPARING);
    }
```

as `mCurrentState` is `STATE_ERROR` seek not work any more, but i can't figure out how to fix my issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's be helpful:

```
    textureView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            //it,s be called without isInPlaybackState()
            mp.seekTo(second);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It's just recommendation how bypass calling `isInPlaybackState()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i can't test this that is work or not, but thanks.

Comment: but as i see documentation of `MediaPlayer` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr0-release/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp i think your code doesn't worked. because media state checked in `seekTo`

Comment: yes you are right. I'm sorry for the incorrect answer.